# The whole furniture here __ provided by IKEA

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Should I use *is* or *are*?, Personally I think the correct answer is using *is* but I have a little doubt in my mind. Can someone help me out? Thank you

Comment: hi! Welcome to ELL! This is not the right place to get your homework done, so please do some reasearch by yourself and edit your question if you still have some doubt.

Comment: I've already done some research and searching, but I still have a little doubt in my mind, that's why I asked a question in ELL.Btw thanks for replying

Comment: Many dictionaries will tell you whether a noun is countable or uncountable.  Uncountable nouns have singular agreement (*is*).  Many uncountable nouns can also be treated as countable (with a different shade of meaning), though often this is less common.  "Uncountable" (or *[U]* in the dictionary's abbreviation) is the only verdict given for "furniture" by Cambridge, for example ( https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/furniture ), and Lexico calls it a "mass noun" (which means the same thing as "uncountable") ( https://www.lexico.com/definition/furniture ).

Answer (score 3):

Grammatically, **furniture** should be treated as singular; it is an uncountable noun. Thus, “The furniture here ***is*** provided by IKEA.”. One does not say “The ***whole*** furniture...”; if one is referring to multiple items of furniture as a collection, it is usual to say “***All of the furniture***...”, and still use the singular form for the verb.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.